# SonarQube check on code then pass to git/repo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops, sonarscanner

I want to check the developer code with SonarQube before push the code into Git.
it is technically possible? if yes please explain, how developer push the code into sonarqube and then passed to git if meet the required quality.

Answer (score 1):

It may be technically possible, but it's not worthwhile.

A better strategy is to use pull requests.  When a pull request is created, based on commits to a feature branch, perform all the quality checks (unit tests, SonarQube, et cetera) on the code on the pull request branch.  If any of your indicated constraints fail (unit test failures, SonarQube quality gates, or build-specific conditions), then have your remote repository configured to not allow the merge of the pull request.  Different repository implementations do this differently (BitBucket, GitLab, GitHub, et cetera).